# Why does the cyclization of open-chain glucose occur via the C5 hydroxyl group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

In converting glucose from its acyclic (open-chain) form to either cyclic form (alpha or beta) why is the C5 hydroxyl group used instead of the bottom-most hydroxyl group?

Also, are these structures considered isomers? All sources I've seen only say "form" or "representation."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the internal [ring strain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_strain) the best possible conformation is a six-membered heterocycle in this case called [pyranose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyranose) . A five-membered heterocycle may in rare cases also be formed, called [furanose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furanose). (From left to right: α-D-Glucopyranose, β-D-Glucopyranose, α-D-Glucofuranose, β-D-Glucofuranose; courtesy of [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose#Cyclic_forms))
[image: α-D-Glucopyranose]  [image: β-D-Glucopyranose]  [image: α-D-Glucofuranose]  [image: β-D-Glucofuranose]
Including the linear chain form they are all [isomers](http://goldbook.iupac.org/I03289.html) ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomer)), as they have the same chemical formula. More specifically the relationship between $\ce{linear <-> pyranose <-> furanose}$ is called constitutional or structural isomer.
The $\ce{\alpha-D <-> \beta-D}$ forms are diastereomers, or more specific diastereomeric conformers.

Answer (score 3):

The cyclic form of glucose uses the C5 oxygen for bonding since it forms a 6 member ring (more stable then either 5 or 7 member ring).

They are isomers since they have the same chemical formula.